# Where can I download the latest gitx app (dmg) from gitx branch

Tags: git, gitx

The gitx version on trunk is out of date, 
https://github.com/pieter/gitx/wiki/

but its time consuming to download and compile the latest code from branch.
https://github.com/laullon/gitx/tree/
Has any one got a download link to a latest branch build?

Answer (score 6):

You can find the latest download links at [www.gitx.org](http://www.gitx.org).

I recently bought the gitx.org domain and created [this site](http://www.gitx.org). It's meant to give an overview of the available forks, with links to the latest version of each fork. The site hasn't been online for a week yet, so any input is very welcome at this stage.

Comment: Become an affiliate for Tower and sell their software. It's heaps better.

Comment: @johndpope I'm not sure I follow. Do you mean that I should sell software instead of promoting open source software?

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor this [GitX page](http://gitx.posterous.com/).

For instance [GitX0.8.2beta has a package ready to be downloaded](https://github.com/downloads/laullon/gitx/GitX_V082_beta.zip).
(I didn't see the one for 0.8.2 final though)